# Ограничение значения при создании таблицы Oracle

Tags: база-данных, oracle, plsql

Необходимо для столбца amount задать значение от 1 до 15, чтобы не было возможности внести в таблицу значения с другим количеством.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут подойдет ограничение CHECK:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table
ADD CONSTRAINT amount_range 
CHECK (amount BETWEEN 1 AND 15);
```

Или можно вообще задать ограничение при создании таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE your_table (
    ...,
    amount NUMBER(2) CHECK (amount BETWEEN 1 AND 15)
);
```

Comment: Спасибо за быстрый ответ! все работает.